# Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//)

Tags: perl

i try to hit my perl script in the browser and it gives Internal Server Error

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

when i check the server logs at the line the line is 
if ($content1 =~ m/IP/g) 
`{`
        $value1=pos($content1);
        }

please help

Comment: Does your script run fine if executed manually? post your script and the line number which is causing this error

Comment: isnt `/g` mainly for `s/` usage? Have you tried removing it?

Comment: Are you sure there's no other errors in the log? This warning is just that - a warning; it won't stop the script's execution.

Comment: @KarthikT: the `/g` is superfluous but it won't cause any problems with this code.

Comment: @Borodin, Actually, it can cause problems. Not the kind he's seeing, though.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include the error message.

Comment: @ikegami: What are you thinking of? The implicit `\G` anchor?

Comment: @Borodin, yes. (It's more like `\G(?s:.*?)` instead of the normal `\A(?s:.*?)`.)

Answer (score 2):

From your title I assume you have an error message that says

```
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match
```

somewhere. You should put that in your question.

The problem is that `$content1` is `undef` at the time of the attempted pattern match. We can't guess why that might be unless you show more of your code.

Answer (score -1):

In order to get rid of that warning you could simply:

```
 if ( $content1 and $content1 =~ m/IP/g) { $value1=pos($content1); }
```

But that is a warning, and is not causing you the `internal server error`

Comment: -1 for silencing a warning without any indication that there's no error. (Not to mention, this doesn't answer the OP's question at all.)

Comment: well, the `if` tests if `$content` contains `IP`. If it's `undefined` it definitely doesn't contain it. WHY it is undefined is below the scope of the code posted, it might indicate an error, or might be the intended behaviour. That is probably why Perl is returning a `warning`

Comment: Exactly, it might indicate an error. That error should be handled; the message indicating that error shouldn't be silenced. Your code is almost surely a bad solution to something you claim is out of scope.

Comment: the *almost* in your phrase denotes an assumption. what makes you think that your assumption is better than mine? :)

Comment: I didn't make any assumption; I'm merely pointing that you made one (and a very bad one at that).

Comment: you assumed that the code that is not shown depends critically on that `$content1` variable.

Comment: I have no idea what that means, but I didn't do that. I showed that you assumed the opposite.

Comment: I am using this technique of getting rid of that warning all over my code and it didn't create any problems (yet). Anyway, thanks for mentioning the reason for downvoting my answer.

Comment: `$line = <>; print $line;`, and I could list a million others. There's a reason Perl is issuing an error message, and it's because an error likely occurred. I don't think I've *ever* used code of the form you suggest, but that's not why. It's that I disagree with telling a newbie to just silence a warning without explaining why it's spurious, or as is the case here, without even attempting to discover if it us spurious at all.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this warning is issued since perl 5.10 .  If it caused that many errors, it would've been added earlier. Also, until now, this warning only caused me the necessity to add more code to silence it, I don't remember any case where it helped me to find a bug

Comment: No. 5.6 and 5.8 had it, and I wager heftily that it existed before that; I just have no experience with older versions.

Comment: it must be a more generic "Use of uninitialized value in ... " warning that was introduced in 5.10, because when we migrated some huge code base from 5.8, the logs suddenly started filling with that warning.

Comment: Not at all. The only thing that changed is that they added the name of the undef var to the message. ("Use of uninitialized value **$x** in concatenation" vs "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation".) Maybe you had a filter for the old message that failed when the message changed.